# ERROR - SSH operator error: timed out in Airflow while connecting with ec2 instance

Tags: python, airflow

I am getting a timeout error while trying to connect with ec2 instance.
I can connect to the machine through ssh command:

> ssh -i keypair.pem myuser@ec2IPaddress

My connection file has the following things:

> conn Id: ssh_custom 
>   Conn Type: SSH 
>   Host: ec2IPaddress 
>   Username: myuser
>   Port: 8888 
>   Extra: {"key_file":"/home/ubuntu/keypair.pem", "no_host_key_check": "false", "allow_host_key_change": "true", "timeout": "45"}

My dag file looks like:

```
from airflow import DAG
import datetime as dt
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.contrib.hooks.ssh_hook import SSHHook
from airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator import SSHOperator

sshHook = SSHHook(ssh_conn_id='ssh_custom')

default_args = {
    'owner': 'arpita',
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2019, 11, 20),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['example@abc.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
}

with DAG('sample',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval='30 * * * *',
         ) as dag:
     task1 = SSHOperator(task_id="task1",
                         command='echo $HOSTNAME',
                         ssh_hook=sshHook)

task1
```

Getting the error:

```
ERROR - SSH operator error: timed out
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator.py", line 101, in execute
    with self.ssh_hook.get_conn() as ssh_client:
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/ssh_hook.py", line 180, in get_conn
    sock=self.host_proxy)
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 349, in connect
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/util.py", line 280, in retry_on_signal
    return function()
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 349, in <lambda>
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 926, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator.py", line 173, in execute
    raise AirflowException("SSH operator error: {0}".format(str(e)))
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: SSH operator error: timed out
[2019-11-26 15:23:20,254] {taskinstance.py:1080} INFO - All retries failed; marking task as FAILED
[2019-11-26 15:23:20,284] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [[34m2019-11-26 15:23:20,284[0m] {[34mconfiguration.py:[0m299} WARNING[0m - section/key [[1msmtp[0m/[1msmtp_user[0m] not found in config[0m
[2019-11-26 15:23:20,284] {taskinstance.py:1086} ERROR - Failed to send email to: ['example@abc.com']
[2019-11-26 15:23:20,285] {taskinstance.py:1087} ERROR - [Errno 111] Connection refused
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator.py", line 101, in execute
    with self.ssh_hook.get_conn() as ssh_client:
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/ssh_hook.py", line 180, in get_conn
    sock=self.host_proxy)
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 349, in connect
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/util.py", line 280, in retry_on_signal
    return function()
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 349, in <lambda>
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 926, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator.py", line 173, in execute
    raise AirflowException("SSH operator error: {0}".format(str(e)))
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: SSH operator error: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1084, in handle_failure
    self.email_alert(error)
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1307, in email_alert
    send_email(self.task.email, subject, html_content)
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 55, in send_email
    mime_subtype=mime_subtype, mime_charset=mime_charset, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 101, in send_email_smtp
    send_MIME_email(smtp_mail_from, recipients, msg, dryrun)
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 121, in send_MIME_email
    s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(SMTP_HOST, SMTP_PORT) if SMTP_SSL else smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_HOST, SMTP_PORT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 335, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 306, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 711, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 702, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: Are you sure you set up your SSH keys correctly? Also, double check to make sure your instance doesn't have any firewall rules that conflict

Answer (score 4):

The problem is solved, actually, the port number 8888 was incorrect. It worked with port number 22.

Comment: I am trying to set connection from airflow to my aws ec2 linux server using ssh connection option. Normally I am able to ssh to that ec2 instance but I try Airflow ssh connection test I get [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ‘/Users/archanakarpe/Downloads/20-march.pem’

Comment: Path and permission works when I directly ssh to that ec2 instance. So as cloudwalker.io/2019/09/01/airflow-connections/… airflow-connections document is saying Note: There are a couple of catches before you jump ahead Make sure you are able to access your Linux box from airflow server before jumping head. Install the following python library and its dependencies ssh_tunnel So could someone help me how to set this ssh_tunnel in this case or is something else I am doing wrong? Please guide me